# Where are wallet files located (Mac OS)

Tags: monero-wallet-cli

I have been away the last few months from my laptop and now upgrading to 0.10.3.1 from 0.10.0.0.
In the post on Reddit it says that I should copy my wallet files into the directory with the 0.10.3.1 binaries.
However I cannot find where any of the 3 files (wallet.keys, wallet and wallet.address) are actually located. They are not in the 0.10.0.0 binary folder and when I search for these names nothing is found.
To be honest I do not recall ever using these files, but I do know that I had a wallet and was able to access it by running monero-wallet-cli and typing in the wallet name and password. 
Does anyone have any suggestions on where these files might be found?

Comment: The wallet files are actually named <wallet name> <wallet name>.keys <wallet name>.address. Try searching for *.keys if you don't remember your wallet name

Answer (score 2):

I'm using a Mac OS right now and looks like it will be saved in /Users/[Your-User] when you just type the wallet without adding any path.

There should be a filename their with the name of your wallet.

Comment: There should be a directory called Monero. Under that directory should be a directory called wallet (e.g. ~/Monero/wallet)

Comment: Might also check `~/.bitmonero/wallets/`

Answer (score 2):

**Under Windoze: C:\Users\user name\Documents\Monero\wallets\user name**

Answer (score 0):

/Users/[your_user]/Monero/wallets/